# How to fix DVC error 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory' in Github actions

Tags: dvc

Trying to pull a folder with test data into a GitHub actions container, I get

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I tried running `dvc checkout --relink` locally, but that did not work. I am using Gdrive for the data-repository with a service account. It seems the login works. But strangely the file is not present. Maybe I can push the files again somehow and recreate the data in the repository?

---

### `dvc doctor` output:

```
DVC version: 2.10.2 (pip)
---------------------------------
Platform: Python 3.7.13 on Linux-5.15.0-1014-azure-x86_64-with-debian-bullseye-sid
Supports:
    gdrive (pydrive2 = 1.14.0),
    webhdfs (fsspec = 2022.5.0),
    http (aiohttp = 3.8.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.5.2),
    https (aiohttp = 3.8.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.5.2)
Cache types: <https://error.dvc.org/no-dvc-cache>
Caches: local
Remotes: gdrive
Workspace directory: ext4 on /dev/sda1
Repo: dvc, git
```

I was able to clone the GIT repo and pull the data from the DVC data-registry, however, it did not work from GH.

---

### Full traceback

```
Successfully installed PyYAML-6.0 aiohttp-3.8.1 aiohttp-retry-2.5.1 aiosignal-1.2.0 appdirs-1.4.4 async-timeout-4.0.2 asynctest-0.13.0 atpublic-2.3 attrs-21.4.0 cached-property-1.5.2 cachetools-4.2.4 certifi-2022.6.15 cffi-1.15.1 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 colorama-0.4.5 commonmark-0.9.1 configobj-5.0.6 contextvars-2.4 cryptography-37.0.4 dataclasses-0.8 decorator-4.4.2 dictdiffer-0.9.0 diskcache-5.4.0 distro-1.7.0 dpath-2.0.6 dulwich-0.20.45 dvc-2.8.1 flatten-dict-0.4.2 flufl.lock-3.2 frozenlist-1.2.0 fsspec-2022.1.0 ftfy-6.0.3 funcy-1.17 future-0.18.2 gitdb-4.0.9 gitpython-3.1.18 google-api-core-2.8.2 google-api-python-client-2.52.0 google-auth-2.9.1 google-auth-httplib2-0.1.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.56.3 grandalf-0.6 httplib2-0.20.4 idna-3.3 idna-ssl-1.1.0 immutables-0.18 importlib-metadata-4.8.3 importlib-resources-5.4.0 mailchecker-4.1.18 multidict-5.2.0 nanotime-0.5.2 networkx-2.5.1 oauth2client-4.1.3 packaging-21.3 pathspec-0.8.1 phonenumbers-8.12.52 ply-3.11 protobuf-3.19.4 psutil-5.9.1 pyOpenSSL-22.0.0 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pycparser-2.21 pydot-1.4.2 pydrive2-1.10.1 pygit2-1.6.1 pygments-2.12.0 pygtrie-2.5.0 pyparsing-2.4.7 python-benedict-0.25.2 python-dateutil-2.8.2 python-fsutil-0.6.1 python-slugify-6.1.2 requests-2.27.1 rich-12.5.1 rsa-4.9 ruamel.yaml-0.17.21 ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.6 shortuuid-1.0.9 shtab-1.5.5 six-1.16.0 smmap-5.0.0 tabulate-0.8.10 text-unidecode-1.3 toml-0.10.2 tqdm-4.64.0 typing-extensions-4.1.1 uritemplate-4.1.1 urllib3-1.26.10 voluptuous-0.13.1 wcwidth-0.2.5 xmltodict-0.13.0 yarl-1.7.2 zc.lockfile-2.0 zipp-3.6.0
DVC version: 2.8.1 (pip)
---------------------------------
Platform: Python 3.6.15 on Linux-5.15.0-1014-azure-x86_64-with-debian-bullseye-sid
Supports:
    gdrive (pydrive2 = 1.10.1),
    webhdfs (fsspec = 2022.1.0),
    http (aiohttp = 3.8.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.5.1),
    https (aiohttp = 3.8.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.5.1)
Cache types: <https://error.dvc.org/no-dvc-cache>
Caches: local
Remotes: gdrive
Workspace directory: ext4 on /dev/sdb1
Repo: dvc, git
2022-07-22 19:01:08,361 DEBUG: failed to pull cache for 'tests/data'
2022-07-22 19:01:08,364 WARNING: No file hash info found for 'tests/data'. It won't be created.
1 file failed
2022-07-22 19:01:08,365 ERROR: failed to pull data from the cloud - Checkout failed for following targets:
tests/data
Is your cache up to date?
<https://error.dvc.org/missing-files>
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.15/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dvc/command/data_sync.py", line 41, in run
    glob=self.args.glob,
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.15/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dvc/repo/__init__.py", line 50, in wrapper
    return f(repo, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.15/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dvc/repo/pull.py", line 44, in pull
    recursive=recursive,
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.15/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dvc/repo/__init__.py", line 50, in wrapper
    return f(repo, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.15/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dvc/repo/checkout.py", line 110, in checkout
    raise CheckoutError(stats["failed"], stats)
dvc.exceptions.CheckoutError: Checkout failed for following targets:
tests/data
Is your cache up to date?
<https://error.dvc.org/missing-files>
------------------------------------------------------------
2022-07-22 19:01:08,369 DEBUG: Analytics is enabled.
2022-07-22 19:01:08,412 DEBUG: Trying to spawn '['daemon', '-q', 'analytics', '/tmp/tmp6i9uchzh']'
2022-07-22 19:01:08,413 DEBUG: Spawned '['daemon', '-q', 'analytics', '/tmp/tmp6i9uchzh']'
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

Comment: It sounds like the file doesn't exist in the remote. It should be `dvc push`ed first from wherever it originated. Please provide more context (e.g. full error traceback with `dvc pull -v`) and/or contact https://dvc.org/support if you need further help.

Comment: I did that already. It is not working on Github.

Comment: The traceback is helpful but I still can't understand the full context. I'm confused by the statement that you can pull from a data registry (what data registry?) but not "from GH". The data isn't pulled from Github but from remote storage (Gdrive in this case) -- where it needs to be pushed to first. Also have you seen the 2 error links in the output you shared? They may be helpful: https://error.dvc.org/no-dvc-cache and https://error.dvc.org/missing-files.

Comment: DVC uses a data-registry to store data remotely. GH then pulls the data from that registry, e.g. to run tests or to train a machine learning model. I am using a google drive folder.

Comment: I get what you mean by "from GH" now. In the GH Actions environment. OK but pulling from a data registry is also unclear. Typically you import from a data registry unless you mean a data remote. See https://dvc.org/doc/use-cases/data-registry

What command is giving that error output in GH, is it `dvc pull`? If so, again, probably the issue is that the files haven't been pushed. And maybe in your local env `pull` doesn't fail because the files are already in your local cache.

Comment: Although the `no-dvc-cache` error is also a mystery here. You should probably try to fix that first.